# JPA join tables through query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, orm

I have strange problem. I want to create database like this:
One student can has a lot of subjects. Student has one evaluation for one subject. So I have
class student with ID, Name, Surname and A_I id, like:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id_student;
```

In subject class I have:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id_subject;
    String name;
double graduate
```

I have third class, named StudentWithGraduate:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;
double evaluation;
@OneToOne
Student student;
@OneToOne
Subject subject;
```

I think I could do it better, but I don't know how. But it isn't a main problem. This, what I write up is working, but I want to do some joins in query like:

```
Vector<Object[]>  v = (Vector<Object[]>) em.createQuery(
"select p.name, o.graduate from Student s 
left join StudentWithGraduate o on s.id_student=o.student
left join Subject p on p.id_subject=o.subject where
s.surname='"+name+"'").getResultList();
```

And it throw an error:
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons.

How can I change this DB scheme or change that query?

Sorry for my english.

PS. When I was doing research I found @joinTables, but I don't know how to use it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [short introduction in JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html), but I will try to quickly explain some missing parts:

In a JPQL query you do *not* write which are the `JOIN` conditions (i.e the `ON` expresions), and instead you navigate through your Entity Graph, beginning with an entity (below I begin with the `StudentWithGraduate` entity):

```
SELECT p.name, o.graduate FROM StudentWithGraduate o
    LEFT JOIN o.student s
    LEFT JOIN o.subject p
    WHERE s.surname=:name
```

The ":name" is called a named parameter, which helps you agains [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In order to set a value for it, you write the following:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(aboveQuery);
query.setParameter("name", parameterValue);
//....the rest of parameters + getResultList();
```

Comment: It's working. I don't know how, but I'll read this page :) if I will have another question I will ask :)